# Redirect user to a page after payment in shopify

Tags: asp.net, shopify, webhooks

I am using shopify,

I send user to shopify with certain product number and quantity, which is being populated with price on shopify where user can make a payment,

Now i want the user to be redirected to a certian page in my website, after successful payment,

I created webhook order payemnt and given the url of the page to be redirected after payment, but it is not working

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to redirect a customer to a different URL depending on the product they purchased, then here is some code I created to do that.

NOTE: This code is inserted into the Additional Scripts section of the Checkout area. To go there go to Settings > Checkout > scroll down to Additional Scripts.

This solutions uses the [Shopify checkout object selector @Altin provided](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Apps/Redirect-user-to-a-page-after-payment-in-shopify/m-p/501013/highlight/true#M15367).

Keep in mind, this solution works uniquely for my Shopify experience because customers can only buy 1 product at a time. If your customers can add multiple items to their carts, than a `for` loop should be used, likely around the `for in` loop.

```
<script>  
  const idUrlList = {
    // Replace the content below here with your own
    "product1": {
      "url": "https://www.URL-HERE.com",
      "product_id": 1234567898765,
    },
    "product2": {
      "url": "https://www.URL-HERE.com",
      "product_id": 1234567898765,
    },
    "product3": {
      "url": "https://www.URL-HERE.com",
      "product_id": 1234567898765,
    },
    "product4": {
      "url": "https://www.URL-HERE.com",
      "product_id": 1234567898765,
    },
    // Replace the content above here with your own
  };

  // Do NOT change anything below this line
  const productPurchasedId = Shopify.checkout.line_items[0].product_id;
  for (const product in idUrlList) {
    if (idUrlList[product].product_id === productPurchasedId) {
      window.location.replace(`${idUrlList[product].url}`);
    }
    else {
        console.log(`Found no matches in dictionary.
        The dictionary ID is ${idUrlList[product].product_id}
        The product ID is ${productPurchasedId}`);
    };
  };
</script>
```

To make this work for you, make the following replacements:

1. Replace "product1" with the name of the product or redirect that you will find memorable. For example, in one of mine I wrote "20_off_2020".
2. Replace https://www.URL-HERE.com with the link you want people to go to. For example, https://theamsalems.com/
3. Replace 1234567898765 with the unique product ID that you want to check for. This can be found in Shopify. Go to Products, click on a product, and grabbing the string of numbers at the end of the URL.
4. Add/remove the other products  depending on how many products you have. For example, if you only have two products, remove the code from "product3" all the way up to the line which says `// Replace the content above here with your own`.

The rest of this code will automatically handle finding product IDs and handling their correct redirects.

Here are some of my references to building this solution:

1. [Shopify checkout object, line_items array](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/checkout#checkout-line_items)
2. [Line items product ID](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/line_item#line_item-product_id)

I also found out you can test your pages using a Bogus Gateway. [Shopify documentation available here](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/test-orders).

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a redirect by visiting Settings > Checkout and pasting this into the text box for Additional content & scripts.

```
<style type="text/css">body {display:none}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.replace("http://yahoo.com");
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any parameters available to pass these URLs to Shopify and then Shopify will take decision on the basis of Success and Failure and Redirect acordingly.